# Spark Notebook: Does GeoPointsChart accept a Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, geopoints, spark-notebook

I have a Dataframe which has two columns latitude and longitude. I passed that to GeoPointsChart. The output is "showing 1000 rows" but it isn't actually showing me anything. Has anyone faced the same issue? Is this a syntactical mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with this notebook, but it looks like you have an API call somewhere producing a `java.util.List`. That class does not have a `toSeq` method. You want to convert `java.util.List` into its Scala equivalent.

First, import this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

This import enriches (or pimps) the Java collections with an `asScala` method to do the conversion:

```
val testAsScala = test.asScala.toSeq
```

I would note though that the call to `toSeq` is unnecessary since the result already mixes in `Seq`. Still, with `asScala` you can now work entirely with Scala collections, which are so much easier.